# Как удалить массив из Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, словари

Есть список

```
var dic = new Dictionaty<string,int>();
```

Есть отдельно список . Я назвал его `stopWords`

```
var stopWords = new List<string>();
```

Как через `linq` сделать двойной цикл, который будет проверять наличие элементов stopWords в словаре `dic`? И если совпадения есть то мы удаляем его из `dic`.

Я вижу решение с помощью создания двойного цикла, но хотелось бы увидеть через `linq`

Comment: Так если видите решение через двойной цикл, почему бы его сюда не добавить?

Comment: Щас добавим.......

Answer (score 3):

Что-то вроде:

```
stopWords.ForEach(sw => 
    {
        dic.Keys.Where(k => k.Contains(sw)).ToList().ForEach(k =>
        {
            dic.Remove(k);
        }
    });
```

Протестить можно [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CDZ8r4).

Ключевой момент: `k => k.Contains(sw)` использует [`String.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) метод, который ищет подстроку в строке.

Дополнительная документация:

- [`List.ForEach()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`ICollection.Constains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx) либо [`Dictionary.ContainsKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Dictionary.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Remove` не бросает исключений, так что можно предварительно не проверять `Contains`. И `ForEach`, который на каждой итерации вызывает метод (лямбду), я бы заменил на простой `foreach` (угу, я люблю микрооптимизации).

Comment: Contains некорректно работает почему то. https://snag.gy/oRAGdZ.jpg

Comment: Потому что `немецкий` коллекция не содержит. Коллекция содержит `немецкий овчарка`. Вам надо чтобы находило и по подстроке?

Comment: хм, а как сделать чтобы просто совпадение искал, не полнотекстовое. А как в обычной строке

Comment: точнее наоборот. В общем чтобы искало как в обычной строке. Для словаря он как то по другому работает

Comment: @Radzhab обновил.

Comment: @AGS17: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 1):

Вы не должны использовать LINQ только потому, что это модно. LINQ нужно использовать по делу, тогда код будет проще.

Смысл LINQ состоит в Q — Query. LINQ применяется для того, чтобы *опросить* нужные данные, а не для того, чтобы *модифицировать* их. С модификацией традиционный код справляется куда лучше.

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
var badKeys = dict.Keys.Where(k => stopWords.Any(w => k.Contains(w))).ToList(); // LINQ-опрос
// ToList() нужно, т. к. мы собираемся модифицировать несущую коллекцию
foreach (var key in badKeys) // модификация в традиционном стиле
    dict.Remove(key);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/KxrhzQ